# Action on callback initializer (KeyboardToolbar)

Tags: swift, xcode, api, swiftui

Newbie here, I'm learning how to use the API "KeyboardToolbar" which allows to add toolbars above the keyboard easily in SwiftUI. I want the items of that toolbar to do an action when pressed but I do not know how to do it. My simple testig code is:

```
import SwiftUI
import KeyboardToolbar

struct KeyToolbar: View {
    
    @State var text = ""
    
    func addText() {
        self.text = "Hello!"
    }
    
    let toolbarItems: [KeyboardToolbarItem] = [
        .init(systemName: "plus.circle", callback: {addText()}),
        .init(systemName: "italic", callback: {}),
        .init(systemName: "underline", callback: {}),
        .dismissKeyboard
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Text:", text: $text)
            .keyboardToolbar(toolbarItems)
    }
}
```

I get an error that says: **Cannot use instance member 'addText' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available**

I've tried searching how to solve that but I have no clue. How could I perform an action with my keyboard toolbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your `toolbarItems` a computed property instead of a `let` declaration -- that way, it'll have access to `addText`:

```
var toolbarItems: [KeyboardToolbarItem] {
        return [
            .init(systemName: "plus.circle", callback: {addText()}),
            .init(systemName: "italic", callback: {}),
            .init(systemName: "underline", callback: {}),
            .dismissKeyboard
        ]
    }
```